# Why doesn't first() behave like :first?

Tags: jquery

Given a simple `<ul>` as so:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

We can move the first item and make it the last like so:

```
// Make the first list item the last list item:
$('#myList li:first').appendTo('#myList')
```

As seen here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

Why doesn't this do the same thing? `$('#myList').first().appendTo($('#myList'))`

Comment: `$('#myList li').first()`

Comment: Yup! That's it...silly mistake. :|

Answer (score 4):

The selector is incorrect

```js
$('#myList li').first().appendTo($('#myList'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```